# Analytic solution for angle of minimum deviation?

Tags: optics, geometry, refraction, geometric-optics

[image]

Consider a simple prism with a prism angle $A$, angle of incidence $\theta_1$, angle of emergence $\theta_4$ and the first and second angle of refraction as $\theta_2,\theta_3$. the refractive index for the prism (w.r.t the surroundings) is $n$. The angle of deviation is $\delta$.I wanted to derive an equation that could give the relation between $\theta_1$ and $\delta$, plot of which for a monochromatic light is as in the [animation here](http://www.wontu.fr/animation-prism.htm). Below is my failed attempt (equations 2 and 3 are from the [geometry of the figure)](http://www.tutorvista.com/content/physics/physics-iv/optics/prism.php):-
$$\theta_4=\sin^{-1}n\sin(\theta_3)$$
$$A+\delta=\theta_1+\theta_4$$
$$A=\theta_2+\theta_3$$
$$\delta=\theta_1+\sin^{-1}n\sin(\theta_3)-A$$
$$\delta=\theta_1+\sin^{-1}n\sin(A-\theta_2)-A$$
$$\delta=\theta_1+\sin^{-1}n\sin(A-\sin^{-1}\frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{n})-A$$
Equation, when I plotted it on [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y=x%2barcsin%281.5sin%20%28%20pi/3-arcsin%28sinx/1.5%29%29%29-pi/3%20for%200.4875%3Cx%3Cpi/2) for an equilateral prism with $n$=$1.5$ yielded the required plot in the limit $28.5^\circ<\theta_1<90^\circ$ (to avoid total internal reflection). But then, how do I use this equation, to analytically find the angle of minimum deviation, and the fact that at minimum deviation $\theta_1=\theta_4$. (I tried taking the derivative, but it turned out to be too complex).

Comment: This contains an analytic derivation http://web.centre.edu/jason.neiser/Classes/Phy230Files/MinimumDeviation.pdf

Comment: The link given by @Sandesh Kalantre in his comment above is not available.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

We'll express the emergent angle $\:\mathrm{i}_{2}\:$ and the deviation angle $\:\delta\:$ as functions of the incident angle $\:\mathrm{i}_{1}$ and after this we'll find the condition that minimizes the deviation angle $\:\delta$.

From Figure-01  we have
\begin{align}
\sin\mathrm{i}_{1} & = \dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\sin\mathrm{i}_{1}^{\prime}\qquad  \text{Snell's Law at point }\color{red}{\boldsymbol{1}} 
\tag{01a}\\
\sin\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime} & = \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\sin\mathrm{i}_{2}\qquad  \text{Snell's Law at point }\color{red}{\boldsymbol{2}} 
\tag{01b}\\
\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}  & = \mathrm A - \mathrm{i}_{1}^{\prime}\qquad \quad \!\text{from triangle }\color{red}{\boldsymbol{124}} 
\tag{01c}\\
\delta & = \omega_{1}+\omega_{2}=\left(\mathrm{i}_{1}-\mathrm{i}_{1}^{\prime}\right)+\left(\mathrm{i}_{2}-\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\right)=\mathrm{i}_{1}+\mathrm{i}_{2}-\underbrace{\left(\mathrm{i}_{1}^{\prime}+\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\right)}_{\mathrm A}
\nonumber\\
\Longrightarrow \quad \delta & = \mathrm{i}_{1}+\mathrm{i}_{2}-\mathrm A  \qquad \!\text{from triangle }\color{red}{\boldsymbol{123}}
\tag{01d}
\end{align} 
so
\begin{align}
\mathrm{i}_{2} & \stackrel{(\rm 01b)}{=\!=\!=} \arcsin\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\sin\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\right)\stackrel{(\rm 01c)}{=\!=\!=} \arcsin\left[\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\sin\left(\mathrm A - \mathrm{i}_{1}^{\prime}\right)\right]
\nonumber\\
& \stackrel{(\rm 01a)}{=\!=\!=}\arcsin\left[\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\sin\left(\mathrm A - \arcsin\left[ \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\sin\mathrm{i}_{1}\right]\right)\right]
\nonumber\\
 & =\!=\!=\arcsin\left[\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\left(\sin\mathrm A\sqrt{1- \left(\dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}} -\cos\mathrm A  \dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\sin\mathrm{i}_{1}\right)\right]
\nonumber\\ 
& =\!=\!=\arcsin\left(\sin\mathrm A\cdot\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}- \sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}} -\cos\mathrm A \sin\mathrm{i}_{1}\right)
\nonumber
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{i}_{2}\left(\mathrm{i}_{1}\right)=\arcsin\left(\sin\mathrm A\cdot\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}- \sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}} -\cos\mathrm A \sin\mathrm{i}_{1}\right)
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
and from (01d)
\begin{equation}
\delta\left(\mathrm{i}_{1}\right)=\mathrm{i}_{1} +\underbrace{\arcsin\left(\sin\mathrm A\cdot\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}- \sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}} -\cos\mathrm A \sin\mathrm{i}_{1}\right)}_{\mathrm{i}_{2}}-\mathrm A
\tag{03}
\end{equation}

To find the minimum deviation angle we start from
\begin{equation}
\delta\left(\mathrm{i}_{1}\right)=\mathrm{i}_{1} +\underbrace{\arcsin\left[\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\sin\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\right]}_{\mathrm{i}_{2}}-\mathrm A
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
and so 
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm d \delta \hphantom{_{1}}}{\mathrm d\mathrm{i}_{1}}  = & \:1 +\dfrac{\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\cos\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}}}\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}}{\mathrm d\mathrm{i}_{1}} 
\nonumber\\
\stackrel{(\rm 01a)}{=\!=\!=} & \:1 +\dfrac{\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\cos \mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2} \mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}}}\dfrac{\dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\cos\mathrm{i}_{1}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}}}
\nonumber\\
=\!=\!=& \:1+\dfrac{\cos\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\cdot\cos\mathrm{i}_{1}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}}\:\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}}} 
\nonumber
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm d \delta \hphantom{_{1}}}{\mathrm d\mathrm{i}_{1}}=1+\dfrac{\cos\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\cdot\cos\mathrm{i}_{1}\vphantom{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}}}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}}\:\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}}}
\tag{05}
\end{equation} 
Now
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm d \delta \hphantom{_{1}}}{\mathrm d\mathrm{i}_{1}} & =0 \qquad \Longrightarrow
\nonumber\\
\cos\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\cdot\cos\mathrm{i}_{1} & = -\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}}\:\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}}\qquad \Longrightarrow
\nonumber\\
\cos^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\cdot\cos^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1} & = \left[1-\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\right]\:\left[1-\left(\dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}\right]\qquad  \Longrightarrow
\nonumber\\
\left(1-\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\right)\cdot\left(1-\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1} \right)& = \left[1-\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\right]\:\left[1-\left(\dfrac{n_{1}}{n_{2}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}\right]\qquad  \Longrightarrow
\nonumber\\
\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1} & = \left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)^{2}\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}\stackrel{(\rm 01b)}{=\!=\!=} \sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}
\tag{06}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{1}=\sin^{2}\mathrm{i}_{2}
\tag{07}
\end{equation} 
Since $\:\mathrm{i}_{1},\mathrm{i}_{2}\in \left[0,\pi/2\right]\:$ the condition for extreme deviation angle is
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{i}_{1}=\mathrm{i}^{*}=\mathrm{i}_{2}
\tag{08}
\end{equation} 
But then
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{i}_{1}^{\prime}=\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}
\tag{09}
\end{equation}
so from (01c)
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{i}_{1}^{\prime}=\dfrac{\mathrm A}{2}=\mathrm{i}_{2}^{\prime}
\tag{10}
\end{equation}
From (01a)
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{i}^{*}=\arcsin\left[\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{\mathrm A}{2}\right)\right]
\tag{11}
\end{equation}
Finally for the minimum deviation angle we have, see (01d),
\begin{equation}
\delta^{*}=2\cdot\mathrm{i}^{*}-\mathrm A =2\cdot\arcsin\left[\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{\mathrm A}{2}\right)\right]-\mathrm A
\tag{12}
\end{equation}
From (12)  the  refraction index of the prism material relative to the surrounding material could be expressed as function of the prism angle $\:\mathrm A\:$ and the minimum deviation angle $\:\delta^{*}\:$ 
\begin{equation}
\left(\dfrac{n_{2}}{n_{1}}\right)=\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\mathrm A + \delta^{*}}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\dfrac{\mathrm A}{2}\right)} 
\tag{13}
\end{equation}

---

**Numerical Example**

[image]

Let
\begin{equation}
\mathrm A =60^{\rm o}\,,\quad n_{1}=1.00\,,\quad n_{2}=1.50
\tag{14}
\end{equation}
From (11)
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{i}^{*}=\arcsin\left[\left(\dfrac{1.50}{1.00}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{60^{\rm o}}{2}\right)\right]=\arcsin\left(0.75\right)=48.59^{\rm o}
\tag{15}
\end{equation}
From (12)
\begin{equation}
\delta^{*}=2\cdot\mathrm{i}^{*}-\mathrm A =2\cdot48.59^{\rm o}-60^{\rm o}=37.18^{\rm o}
\tag{16}
\end{equation}

---

Related : [Why does the graph of deviation angle in a prism doesn't get a symmetry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409713/why-does-the-graph-of-deviation-angle-in-a-prism-doesnt-get-a-symmetry/409844#409844).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is   $$N = \frac{\sin \left((A+D)/2\right)}{\sin (A/2)}$$  at $\theta_1 = \theta$ for    d = deviation, your $\delta$.

From symmetry, one can deduce that when angle 1 equals angle 4, the symmetrical case, then the deviation is either a maximum, or a minimum. The maximum possibility, is easily dismissed, so it must be a minimum.