# A ray through prism

Tags: geometric-optics

A ray with angle of incidence 60° is passed through a prism of angle 15°.

To find the net deviation I know we just apply Snell’s law twice for the ray refracting while going in and while coming out. Here’s my doubt - we find $r_1$ (Angle of refraction 1) to be 30°, and $r_2$ can be found out with the help of the relation $$A=r_1+r_2$$ which we get as -15°, what is the significance of the minus sign?

Comment: I'd really suggest you sketch the beam path and the prism.

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Analytic solution for angle of minimum deviation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82418/analytic-solution-for-angle-of-minimum-deviation/410797#410797). **(2)** [Why does the graph of deviation angle in a prism doesn't get a symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409713/why-does-the-graph-of-deviation-angle-in-a-prism-doesnt-get-a-symmetry/409844#409844). **(3)** [Why one should follow Snell's law for shortest time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257140/why-one-should-follow-snells-law-for-shortest-time/257331#257331).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more understandable visually

This is what a prism with a normal angle looks like; notice the side of the 15°.

[image: This is what a prism with a normal angle looks like, notice the 15 def]

Now consider another prism that is a little thinner. You will notice that the 15° is measured from the OTHER SIDE OF THE RED LINE (normal).

[image: Here is another prism with a smaller angle]

This 15° is written as -15° while writing mathematically. So if you get a negative angle as the answer, then how we measure the angle with respect to the normal is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

It means that, given the axis you have chosen, there's a 15 degrees inclination in the opposite direction. Negative angles don't have any particular or strange meaning, you could as well say it's +345 degrees.

Comment: What do you mean by axis and which direction is opposite?

Comment: When you're expressing angles, you're doing it from a specific axis. Generally we increased angles counterclockwise, and decrease them clockwise. The Y-axis, for example, is 90 degrees WITH RESPECT TO the X-axis. The negative sign just means it's 15 degrees clockwise :)