# Calculation of emergent angle of prism

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Is there a way to calculate emergent angle of an equilateral prism (non-experimentally) ?
I know that one equation that might be helpful is $$\angle D + \angle A = \angle i + \angle e$$
But a single equation isn't enough to calculate the emergent angle.
Given data is : 
Refractive index of prism $(\mu)$, Angle of prism$(\angle A)$& angle of incidence $(\angle i)$

Comment: Related :[Analytic solution for angle of minimum deviation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82418/) and [Why does the graph of deviation angle in a prism doesn't get a symmetry?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409713/) and [Variation of angle of minimum deviation with prism angle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351842/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this calculation is absolutely possible. On your conventions we cannot answer, because you do not fully define your terms, and in any case the calculation is for you to make. The scheme is fairly simple, though:

- Use Snell's law to calculate the angle at which the ray is transmitted into the prism.
- Use the inner triangle formed by the ray and the surfaces of the prism to calculate the angle a which the ray hits the surface of the prism on its way out.
- Use Snell's law to calculate the exit angle.
- Use any additional geometry necessary depending on what angle you actually need to calculate.