# Angle of minimum deviation and prism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, photometry

Does angle of minimum deviation depend on angle of prism?
I know that angle of deviation does but I  don't feel like  the particular behavior is relevant for the angle of deviation as well? Please help me clarify it

Answer (score 1):

For a prism,

$D = I + E - P$

where $D$ is the angle of deviation, $I$ is the incidence angle and E is the angle of emergence with $P$ being the physical angle of the prism.

And when you want the minimum angle of deviation, that is the angle of incidence is the same as the angle of emergence,

$D = 2I - P = 2E - P$

Answer (score 1):

Minimum deviation occurs when the ray passes symmetrically through the prism. You should use this to show for yourself that
$$\sin \left[\frac 12 (A+D_{min})\right]=n \sin \left[\frac A2 \right]$$
in which $n$ is the refractive index of the prism material and $A$ is the angle between the faces via which the ray enters and leaves.

The answer to your question can easily be deduced from this equation.

Comment: *"Minimum deviation occurs when the ray passes symmetrically through the prism"*. Philip, what is the reasoning behind this assertion ??? If the answer is : but then we would have at least two minima, then how do we know a priori that there exists only one minimum ???

Comment: If the ray's path is not symmetrical then the angle of incidence will be different from the angle of emergence. But rays are reversible, so we know that two different angles, $I$,  of incidence will give the same angle of deviation, $D$. Imagine now a graph of $D$ against $I$. In the symmetrical case the two values of $I$ have merged into a single value. Clearly we have either a maximum or a minimum in the graph of $D$ against $I$. I'm sure that you can show for yourself that it is in fact a minimum.

Comment: Philip, what I try to say in my previous comment is shown in this Figure : https://imgur.com/a/0lHgcvw. But now I realize that the deviation curve $\delta(i_1)$ must satisfy a condition with respect to the bisector of the 1rst quadrant.

Comment: And **YES, you are absolutely right.** This condition demands *...the ray to pass symmetrically through the prism* when minimum deviation occurs. Anyway, in my answer here : [Analytic solution for angle of minimum deviation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82418/analytic-solution-for-angle-of-minimum-deviation/410797#410797) this symmetry is proved in an intermediate step, see equations (07)-(10). May be I must append an addendum there to show how this symmetry helps to make things simple.

Comment: @Frobenius You clearly put a lot of work into presenting your analytic solution. Could you please tell me how you produced the nice diagram that accompanies it?

Comment: Philip, from the very beginning in this site I was lucky to "discover" GeoGebra. It's a free software suggested for a time by PSE in the right column. Between others you can produce 3D-drawings and insert equations in $\LaTeX$. See many of these in my answers.

Comment: @Frobenius  Many thanks. I'm an IT ignoramus, but I'll look into GeoGebra.