# How does the minimum deviation change with the prism angle?

Tags: visible-light, refraction

I tried approaching it from the equation $ n=\frac{\sin(\frac{A+D}{2})}{\sin(A/2)} $ I got to this equation $ n= \cos(D/2)+ \cot(A/2)\sin(D/2) $ and i tried to see how D(minimum deviation) changes with A(prism angle) but i couldn't figure it that way.

I did have a simple thought experiment were if i decrease the prism angle to a point where the prism angle is close to 0° the minimum deviation would be close to 0° too. So i have a feeling that the minimum deviation would increase as the prism angle increases. I'm not sure if I'm correct on that please help me clarify it

Comment: @Frobenius yes the graph in the duplicate 2 question is what i was looking for thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the formula you cite: n sin(A/2) = sin[(A + D)/2]  is correct, then use differentials:

n (dA/2) cos(A/2) = [(dA + dD)/2] cos[(A + D)/2] and solve for dD/dA

Comment: I don't think the use of differentials is necessary. Look equation (12) in the Duplicate here [Analytic solution for angle of minimum deviation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82418/analytic-solution-for-angle-of-minimum-deviation/410797#410797)

Comment: I only know limits in calculus for now so i don't know how to do that. edit-

Comment: Frobenius linked a already answered question that solved my issue :)